# Tailwindcss version 3 classes not working on class attributes, but works on @apply for Angular 13

Tags: css, angular, sass, tailwind-css, scss-mixins

I'm unable to get Tailwindcss classes to appear on the inline "class" attribute. But if I @apply I through the ".scss" file and use that class on the inline "class" attribute it works fine.

Does not work:

.HTML

```
<!-- Tailwindcss NOT working -->
<div class="bg-red-500">
    <h1 class="text-9xl">HELLO</h1>
</div>
```

Work:
.scss

```
.bg {
     @apply bg-green-500;
   }

.text {
      @apply text-9xl text-red-500;
    }
```

.HTML

```
<!-- Tailwindcss working -->
    <div class="bg-red-500">
        <h1 class="text-9xl">HELLO</h1>
    </div>
```

Am I missing something? Appreciate the help in advance!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have in `content` property in tailwind.config?

Comment: facing the same issue, I have a content property in the config file.

Comment: also did any one find solution on this?

Comment: In my case, it was just a silly mistake in my content path in the tailwind.config.js. as the tailwind.config.js it was further out of the src folder. So I just wrote the full path and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to try here:

Firstly, make sure that your content settings are correct in your config file:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html}"], //configure this line as you see fit
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**Double-check that the aforementioned line is `content`, not `purge`**

If that's set up correctly, let's make sure you are properly importing tailwind. In your CSS file, add these rules to the top, and make sure that the CSS file is being properly:

```css
/* .src/styles.css */

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's it right there. Make sure the `content` is correct in your tailwind config file. When I updated this, turns out a new folder I created wasn't included in the config so tailwind couldn't read it.

Answer (score 0):

You must be configure your template paths, add the paths to all of your template files in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

```
  module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

You can learn how to connect angular and tailwind css with the link below:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular materials typography will override your Tailwind CSS style, so remove using the material typography and check your it will run fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).